# Standard Navigation Menu in communities using Build Your Own Template

Tags: community-cloud

[image]

I have configured Navigation Menu but not able to find them to add to my page.

Answer (score 2):

There is no drag and drop component in the build your own template, but this page details how you can add one to your layout component:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_example_nav.htm

e.g.

verticalNav.cmp

```
<aura:component extends="forceCommunity:navigationMenuBase">
   <ul>
       <aura:iteration items="{!v.menuItems}" var="item">
           <li>{!item.label}</li>
       </aura:iteration>
   </ul>
</aura:component>
```

Add the component into markup in the layout:

```
<c:verticalNav></c:verticalNav>
```

The items added to the navigation menu will now appear.  You'll need to style and arrange them.

Answer (score 1):

The `navigation menu` is no in the "Build Your Own" template's default theme layout. You should create a custom theme layout component including the nav bar, change the default theme layout in your community/digital site.

1. create a custom theme layout component via developer console or sfdx, actually it's a Lightning Aura Component or lwc. Here's a aura sample:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:themeLayout" access="global" description="Sample Custom Theme Layout">
    <aura:attribute name="search" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="profileMenu" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="navBar" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="newHeader" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <div>
        <div class="searchRegion">
            <!-- Search Publisher component --> 
            {!v.search}
        </div>
        <div class="profileMenuRegion">
            <!-- User Profile Menu component -->
            {!v.profileMenu}
        </div>
        <div class="navigation">
            <!-- Navigation Menu component -->
            {!v.navBar}
        </div>
        <div class="newHeader">
            {!v.newHeader}
        </div>
        <div class="mainContentArea">
            {!v.body}
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Checkout more information about custom theme layout on [this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/forceCommunity:themeLayout/documentation).

2. In the `Experience Builder`, navigate to **Setting** - **Theme**, you can find a `Default` under the `Theme Layouts`, change it's **Theme Layout Component** to your custom theme layout component you created before.
3. refresh the page and you get the navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Custom Links section in the left sidebar.
Enter the URL where you want the item to link to in the URL box.
Enter the menu item text in the Link Text box.
Click Add to Menu.